# What are helper functions in jQuery? Whats its significance in AJAX calls?

Tags: jquery, ajax, ajaxhelper

I was looking deep into AJAX calls and its stages. I got information about Helper functions. As I saw in jQuery official website they had started with three helper functions. But I am not convinced whey they are used.

Please, anyone can guide me with examples?

Comment: Which helper functions specifically? There are lots of them in jQuery.

Comment: First thing i want to know generally why helper functions used. Now specifically i am learning on Ajax call

Comment: They're used for the same reason any function is - to extract logic in to a re-usable block.

Comment: in generally its similar to functions , which means we can create our own helper functions. Sounds good. What about ajax call? Only to format how we pass URL before we make request through ajax call?